# Set password to postfix email users stored in mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, passwords, postfix-mta

I am developing a server control panel, but I haven't been able to set correctly the user password in the mysql database.

The mysql query used to store the password is the following:

```
ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

Yet, I haven't been able to replicate the result in php (of cource, using a static salt): they just don't match.

Here's the php code I have been working with:

```
$salt = '1234567890123456';
$password = 'hello';
$hexhash = hash('sha512', '$6$'. $salt);
// bda6a11cc3aa00b8fe46f0559e86b3e4be3a6646f7dca2df29da1db86cfd7fc0ceb9ca076d16f0296b82e120170f08e049f607cc6e2d7328976f8cb4e8cacf98
$binhash = hex2bin($hexhash);
$hash = base64_encode($binhash);
// vaahHMOqALj+RvBVnoaz5L46Zkb33KLfKdoduGz9f8DOucoHbRbwKWuC4SAXDwjgSfYHzG4tcyiXb4y06MrPmA==
```

The password instead should be just `12NKz5XM5JeKI`.
Any clues about why do the mysql and php implementations differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that, contrary to what I've found looking on Google (some people tried to use the sha512 hash), MySQL `ENCRYPT` function uses just the plain unix `crypt` library, so it is really trivial to implement it in PHP.

Here's the code:

```
$password = 'firstpassword';
$salt = '$6$' . '6bfd195afba021a2';

// or, if you want the random version, 
$password = 'firstpassword';
$salt = '$6$' . substr(md5(microtime()),16);

// And finally the generation
echo crypt($password, $salt);
```

It is sad that nowhere on the internet there was this code, and that's why I've shared it with you :)